# Does Paypal Account Limitation affect Payment Gateway?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I Have been using Paypal Payment Gateway (Buy Now _xclick) for my website.

From yesterday It started to show message as **things don't appear to be working at the moment. please try again later** .

I have Referred the help links and checked my code as well the values passed but I don't find any problem with it.[Paypal Form Generation Help](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/my-payments-standard-integration-isn't-processing-transactions.-what-should-i-do-ts2067/7?channel=MTS)

But when login to my paypal account(Business account) Am getting the below error,

**Your Account is NOW limited. In accordance with applicable laws, we're required to collect information about your organization. You cannot send or receive payments until you provide this information but can continue to withdraw funds from your PayPal Account. Please provide this information before Feb 27, 2018 to remove the limitations on your Account.**

Does this will have any impact on Payment Gateway?

Please suggest me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pay and receive payments in your paypal account,In india paypal transfer funds to your linked bank account i.e the limitation.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan as they mentioned in notification, that seems like only withdrawal is allowed. because it was working still day before yesterday its just stopped suddenly from yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **Big Yes**. Paypal stops transactions when it suspects fraudulent or something risky. You can call customer support to release the limitations of your account.

Please find the link below.
https://www.paypal.com/in/smarthelp/contact-us

For your information, Customer support Phone number differs country to country.
Cheers.